# Graphing a function on turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to graph a function `f1(x)` on turtle. I need to start at `x=-7` and advance .01 until I reach `x=-3`. I also need to use a scale factor of `25`

I've created a for loop in the main function. When I go to the coordinates `(i,i)` and go forward `.01`, then a diagonal line is draw but when I substitute the second `i` for `f1(i)` then nothing happens.

```
def f1(x):
    return 2 * sqrt((-abs(abs(x)-1)) * abs(3 - abs(x))/((abs(x)-1)*  (3-abs(x)))) * \(1 + abs(abs(x)-3)/(abs(x)-3))*sqrt(1-(x/7)**2)+(5+0.97* (abs(x-0.5)+abs(x+0.5))-\3*(abs(x-0.75)+abs(x+0.75)))*(1+abs(1- abs(x))/(1-abs(x)))
def main():
    wn=turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("white")
    wn.title("plotting")
    draw=turtle.Turtle()
    draw.fillcolor("black")
    draw.speed(10)
    draw.penup()
    scale=25
    for i in range(-700,-300,1):
        draw.goto(((i/100)*scale),((f1(i)/100)*scale))
        draw.pendown()
```

I'm not exactly sure what is supposed to be drawn because that's what we're supposed to find out but right now nothing is being drawn, all that happens when I run it is the turtle window opens.

Comment: You want `f1(i/100)`, not `f1(i)/100`.  Also, if you happen to be running this on Python 2.x, change both of the `100`s to `100.0` so that you aren't doing integer division.

Answer (score 1):

I find that forcing code to fit into `range()` can cause more problems than it's worth and a simple `while` loop can sometimes be the way to go:

```
from math import sqrt
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SCALE = 25

def f1(x):  # long line broken up based on where parentheses balance
    return 2 * \
        sqrt((-abs(abs(x) - 1)) * abs(3 - abs(x)) / ((abs(x) - 1) * (3 - abs(x)))) * (1 + abs(abs(x) - 3) / (abs(x) - 3)) * \
        sqrt(1 - (x / 7) ** 2) + \
        (5 + 0.97 * (abs(x - 0.5) + abs(x + 0.5)) - 3 * (abs(x - 0.75) + abs(x + 0.75))) * \
        (1 + abs(1 - abs(x)) / (1 - abs(x)))

wn = Screen()
wn.title("plotting")

draw = Turtle()
draw.speed('fastest')
draw.penup()

i = -7.0

while i < -3.0:
    draw.goto(i * SCALE, f1(i) * SCALE)
    draw.pendown()

    i += 1.0 / 100

wn.exitonclick()
```

Appears to work the same for me under Python 3 or Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to calculate a square root of negative numbers. Corrected code:

```
import turtle
from math import sqrt

def f1(x):
    return 2 * sqrt(abs(abs(x)-1)) * abs(3 - abs(x))/((abs(x)-1)*  (3-abs(x))) * (1 + abs(abs(x)-3)/(abs(x)-3))*sqrt(abs(1-(x/7)**2))+(5+0.97* (abs(x-0.5)+abs(x+0.5))-3*(abs(x-0.75)+abs(x+0.75)))*(1+abs(1- abs(x))/(1-abs(x)))
def main():
    wn=turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("white")
    wn.title("plotting")
    draw=turtle.Turtle()
    draw.fillcolor("black")
    draw.speed(10)
    draw.penup()
    scale=25
    for i in range(-700,-300):
        draw.goto(i*(scale/100),(f1(i)*(scale/100)))
        draw.pendown()
main()
```